# Installing MailChimp.NET package from Visual Studio NuGet manager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

What am I supposed to do to be able to install MailChimp.NET package from Visual Studio NuGet manager?

I get this error:

```
Unable to resolve dependencies. 'jQuery 1.10.2' is not compatible with 'jQuery.UI.Combined 1.8.11 constraint: jQuery (>= 1.4.4)', 'jQuery.Validation 1.11.1 constraint: jQuery (>= 1.4.4)', 'jQuery.vsdoc 1.5.1 constraint: jQuery (= 1.5.1)', 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation 3.1.2 constraint: jQuery (>= 1.8.0)'
```

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell the only thing that withholds the install is the jQuery.vsdoc package. It requires you to have jQuery v1.5.1, while you're using 1.10.2. If you don't need the vsdoc package, try uninstalling it and retry.

Comment: Should I run `Install-Package jQuery 1.5.1` to fix this issue?

Comment: No, you're already using a newer version of jQuery. Try `Install-Package jQuery-vsdoc -Version 1.10.2`. This will install the correct vsdoc package for your current jQuery package

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. Add the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using a newer version of jQuery. Try Install-Package jQuery-vsdoc -Version 1.10.2. This will install the correct vsdoc package for your current jQuery package.